# When I am trying to install cucumber Eclipse Plugin then it is not installing and showing some error

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, cucumber

Error message:

> (Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Cucumber Eclipse Feature
>   0.0.17.201704062133 (cucumber.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.17.201704062133)   Missing requirement: Cucumber Editor 0.0.17.201704062133 (cucumber.eclipse.editor 0.0.17.201704062133) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui 3.5.0' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Cucumber Eclipse Feature 0.0.17.201704062133 (cucumber.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.0.17.201704062133)
>       To: cucumber.eclipse.editor [0.0.17.201704062133])

Comment: This may be because the plugin is not supported for your version of eclipse. You need to use a older version of eclipse or find some other plugin to work

Comment: I have tried with the older versions but error has been not resolved..

Answer (score 1):

The option of `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` should be checked in order to download any missing required dependencies.

Comment: Yes I have checked that while downloading for missing required dependencies but not getting results to resolve this error...

Answer (score 0):

We are using [qaf-bdd-editors](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/qaf-bdd-editors). You can give it try.